# SQL Delete with Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete from a table with the results of a subquery. The results return a unique tuple, and currently I end up deleting more than just the results returned because i'm only checking col1 results.

```
DELETE FROM Table1 exTable
WHERE exTable.col1 = ... AND exTable.col2 = ...
(SELECT col1, col2
FROM ...)
```

Comment: Information provided is not sufficient.

Comment: I want to delete a row based on the results from the sub-query. I tried doing exTable.col1 EXISTS in (SELECT col1 FROM...) but this only deletes rows based off col1. Not sure how to make sure it includes both columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `join` to match more than 1 column.

```
DELETE t1
FROM Table1 t1
inner join 
(
   select col1, col2 
   from other_table 
   where ...
) t2 on  t2.col1 = t1.col1 
     and t2.col2 = t1.col2
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I used this advice to put the results of the subquery into a temp table. And then joined to the temp table. I'll now spend time to see if I can do this without the temp table.

Comment: You can join to a subquery: `select * from (subquery) x on x.col1 = t1.col1` and so on.

Comment: DELETE JOIN is not part of the standard. It is not allowed by Postgres and Oracle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591496/is-delete-from-join-standard-sql

Comment: @LuísdeSousa: MySQL does support it! https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192849/575376. And how is the SQL standard relevant here anyway?

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE JOIN` is not part of the standard. A sub-query must be declared either with a `USING` or `WITH` statement. Below an example with the former.

```sql
DELETE  
  FROM Table1 t1
 USING (SELECT c1, c2, ...
          FROM Table2
         WHERE ...
       ) t2
 WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1
   AND t2.c2 = t2.c2
;
```