# What about SQL join on deleting/updating?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've heard that `update` with `join` is not supported by SQL standard, and MySQL does support it. Any reason for the standard doesn't support it?
What about `delete`? I think both (`update`&`delete` -- or those have `where` substatement in my mind) should support `join`.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591496/is-delete-from-join-standard-sql  , but no detailed reason. (Maybe sub query has good performance than join in some cases?)

Comment: You can use merge statement in sql to updat/delete using join.

Comment: SQL Server supports Update from Join

Comment: I see. What I mean here is if a lot of DBMS support `join`, why the standard does not include this?

Comment: MySQL allows joins in UPDATEs, if that's what you mean

Comment: I mean the SQL standard seems not support that.